# How do I install TikZ on a MacBook?

Tags: installing, mactex

I have no knowledge of programming...

I have a MacBook OS10.6 with Tex Shop, updated...

after placing the zipped file into `/Users/myname/Library/texmf/tex` folder,

I open terminal in utilities and type `texhash`...this is what I get...

```
Last login: Tue Feb 15 12:31:42 on console You have mail.
anns-macbook:~ ann$
anns-macbook:~ ann$ texhash
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local: directory not writable.
Skipping... texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf: directory not writable.
Skipping... texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-config: directory not writable.
Skipping... texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist: directory not writable.
Skipping... texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-var: directory not writable. 
Skipping... texhash: Done.
```

Any ideas, I can't use the `pgf` library in TeX Shop since TeX Shop can't seem to find the library in the folder structure I've created

Comment: You need to call texhash as `root` (no idea how to do that on a mac)

Comment: @ann. You seem to have TeX Live 2010 installed (or perhaps MacTeX 2010). It includes Tikz already: you should not need to add it.

Comment: the manual I have when I search tikz package is 2.0...and I want to use the 2.1 version

Comment: When you say that you have TeXShop, do you mean that you have MacTeX: http://www.tug.org/mactex/ ?  If so, then you should be able to run the "TeX Live Utility" (found in `/Applications/TeX`) to install PGF (and TikZ) if they're not already installed.

Comment: As for your specific problem, you do not ordinarily have write permissions in `/usr` in Mac OS X, so you need to use `sudo texhash` instead of `texhash` (which is essentially what Caramdir is suggesting that you do).

Comment: specifically, when I'm in Tex Shop, and \usepackage{tikz}

Comment: For what it's worth, the current version of PGF/TikZ on my MacTeX 2010 install (updated through the TeX Live Utility) is 2.10.

Answer (score 5):

To summarize what we've learned today:

1. It is by far easier to keep MacTeX packages up-to-date by using the TeX Live Utility than by manually installing packages into `~/Library/texmf` (`~` is UNIX shorthand for the user's home directory, which is `/Users/username` in Mac OS X).
2. (La)TeX commands, like most other computer commands, need to be invoked in exactly the right form.  Simple typos (extra letters, missing letters, unmatched curly braces, etc.) can cause major headaches!  In this case, `\usetikzlibrary{mindmaps}` (plural "mindmaps") is not the same as `\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}` (singular "mindmap").

Comment: this is not really an answer, I think. Some bits are also inaccurate (you don't need `sudo texhash` to hash `~/Library/texhash`, only to hash `/usr/local/texmf`. And indeed you don't need to hash `~/Library/texhash` at all with TeX Live 2010.)

Comment: @Joseph: It's just point 2 that's inaccurate, yes? Specifically, the lack of administrative privileges was responsible for the error messages that ann reported, but the underlying problem was trying to use a TikZ library that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: yes, that's the case

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe my problem isn't what's installed but how I am using MacTex to generate a typeset...

When I begin a document as:

\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmaps}

and use an example from pgfmanual 2.10 from the packagedownload http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/

I get an error that mindmaps isn't found...so I presumed that mindmaps is part of the 2.10 version of tikz/pgf and I attempted to uninstall 2.0 and replace it with the download 2.10...

I've tried placing the downloaded package in /Users/myname/Library/texmf/tex and then running sudo texhash in the terminal, and still MacTex can't typeset the example for mindmaps...

any ideas?

Comment: Please don't post additional information as an answer, but add it to the question. The answer space should be reserved for actual answers.

Comment: @Ann: You should rather edit your original question than provide an "answer". (God, do I feel nit-picky.)

Comment: As other people have said: Instead of manually installing TikZ, use the update tool of MacTeX 2010 (if someone would by me a Mac, I could give you more detailed instructions...).

Comment: @ann: You have to separate unregistered users. Please register your account (I think there should be a link on your profile page). Then some moderator can merge the two accounts and you can edit your question again.

Comment: my apologies, there was no longer a grey 'comment' above for me to add more comments...

Comment: @ann: you should now have just the one account. Please do register it!

Comment: I think the problem here is that you should be using `\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}` instead of `\usetikzlibrary{mindmaps}`.

Comment: @las3rjock: good catch!

Comment: wow, thanks for everyone's time...though I did cut-and-paste the code with the erroneous 's' at the end of mindmap from a tutorial...it should have been the first thing I checked...a lesson learned

Comment: @las3rock: could you convert your comment to an answer so that @ann can accept it?

Comment: @ann: As this is a comment, not an 'answer', it will be removed from public view at some stage. It would be great if you'd do that yourself, once you've registered your account

Comment: @Caramdir: It took me some time to understand why you told Ann to separate unregistered users (and which users she was to separate) `:-)`