# tikz: code just keeps compiling?

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, syntax

I was trying to draw arcs in tikz, and I was using code from
[this site](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) arc (0:270:8mm);
\draw (0,0) arc (0:315:1.75cm and 1cm);
\filldraw[fill=cyan, draw=blue] (0,0) -- (12mm,0mm) arc (0:30:12mm) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this does not work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)  arc[radius = 8mm, start angle= 0, end angle= 270]
\draw (0,0)  arc[x radius = 1.75cm, y radius = 1cm, start angle= 0, end angle= 315]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

He just keeps compiling, absorbing 100% CPU according to my Activity Monitor.
Is this normal? Is it possible something hasn't been installed properly?

Comment: Your second example should gives errors: you are missing `;` at the end of the two `\draw` lines. If I add them in all is well: what version of `pgf` do you have installed?

Comment: Thanks, I used ; but it still doesn't work.  I checked the log-file, it says:
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.12)

Comment: It may well be that the key-value syntax for `arc`s came after that version of PGF.  Take a look at your version of the manual (`texdoc pgf`) to see if that is a valid syntax for specifying `arc`s.  If not, you either have to update TikZ/PGF (recommended) or use the old syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that changes my problem into the one discussed 
<a href="http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11148/how-do-i-install-tikz-on-a-macbook">this site</a>
installing tikz (or updating it)
According to my Tex Live Utility there is nothing new to be installed, and simply downloading a new version and dropping the new pgf folder in Users/myname/Library/texmf/tex/generic doesn't do the job either.