# tikz code runs forever without error message

Tags: tikz-trees

The following code runs forever without producing an output - it worked before I played with multiline labels (undone - what would be the simples solution for three lines for the bottom element?) - and works without drawing the lines to the nodes. Drawing the lines to the nodes gives no error message but does not stop, nor produce an output.

```
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper
    ]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

text 
\begin{tikzpicture}
% First, locate each of the nodes and name them
\node (top) at (0,1) {$\{\} = \top$};
\node  (left) at ((-1.5,0) {$\{\{A+\}=A$};
\node  (right) at (1.5,0){$\{A-\}=\lnot A $};
\node  (bottom) at (0,-1) {$\{A+,A-\} = \bot  =A \lor \lnot A$ }
%
%% Now draw the lines:
\draw [black,  thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt] (top) -- (left);
\draw [black, thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt] (top) -- (right);
\draw [black, thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt] (left) -- (bottom);
\draw [black, thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt] (right) -- (bottom);
\end{tikzpicture}
The multiple applications of a GIS can be summarized in three prototypical situations:

\end{document}
```

Comment: The node `bottom` is missing a closing semicolon. (When in doubt try running pdflatex directly from the command-line.)

Comment: This is a typical issue with TikZ e.g., [Q97996](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97996)

Comment: my stupid mistake - better error messages would be appreciated (and save time).

Comment: In this specific case an error message is not possible due to how TikZ (and actually how TeX parses the input) work because there is no error happened yet. In other words it is stuck at swallowing the input. An error is possible when that is finished. From its perspective because a new draw has come it restarts reading the new `\draw` and the previous one is not finished yet though it already consumed the whole file.

Comment: in my test i receive `Error: Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?`. however it not react on error: `((-1.5,0)` (one open parenthesis is superfluous).

Comment: @Andrew Would you like to add an answer or should we close it as solved in comment?

Comment: solved in comment - really a stupid error but the number of conventions in different languages is taxing!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Let's close a solved in the comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was a typo that was easily solved in the comments.